# Como fazer mega menu estilizado em Wordpress?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Preciso fazer um mega menu parecido com o menu de produtos desse site:

http://www.bmcsoftware.com.br/

Eu uso Wordpress no site que estou trabalhando no momento, não sei se existe plugin para isso, mas o que mais me atrapalha na criação desse menu é por eu estar usando Wordpress e ter que criar os menus pelo `wp-admin`, isso acaba me confundindo.

Ainda não tenho nada produzido até o momento, então qualquer luz já me ajuda.

Comment: Uma dica, faça no braço! os menus feitos através do painel administrativo do wordpress ou plugins geram muita "sujeira" no código, sem falar que são horríveis para manutenção. Utilize HTML e CSS puro, se estiver tendo dificuldade no CSS utilize algum framework para te ajudar como bootstrap ou foundation...

Comment: @DorivalZanetto Valeu pela dica. Eu queria achar um plugin para isso, pois queria que fosse facilmente editado por quem não soube-se mexer no código. Porem também estou com dificuldade de enxergar como farei isso na mão, pois não tenho ideia de como estruturar isso junto com o WP, estou procurando algum exemplo pela internet para ver se me ajuda.

Comment: Giovanni, eu trabalho utilizando um Plugin chamado Advanced custom field (ACF), ele facilita a criação de conteúdo gerenciável, se tiver interesse de uma olhada, acredito que facilite bastante na criação! Estou meio sem tempo agora, mas quando eu tiver com tempo posso elaborar um exemplo utilizando o mesmo caso você ache necessário =]

Comment: @DorivalZanetto Não manjo muito desse plugin, quase usei ele em um problema passado, mas acabei não usando ele por não ter muito conhecimento com ele e por ter conseguido solucionar de outra forma. Mas caso tenha tempo, eu gostaria de ver um exemplo seu sim!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Minha solução foi usar um plugin chamado UberMenu, como não tinha tempo optei pelo mais rápido. Para instalar ele é meio complicado, precisa alterar algumas coisas no seu código, mas me ajudou muito e continua ajudando, por ele ter um painel administrativo é muito fácil ensinar alguem que não tem tanto conhecimento a editar.

Fica a dica do plugin aí, para caso alguém tenha esse problema também.

Answer (score 0):

Bom isso pode ser feito de várias maneiras. Eu faria no braço se fosse você, aplicando os estilos e efeitos que desejasse. Mas caso queria algo pronto e que te facilite usa essa referência:

http://cssmenumaker.com/